# Classifying acid-base reaction between aluminium hydride and lithium hydride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

So I was dealing with a reaction the other day, which is also briefly written in the title:

> $$\ce{AlH3(s) + LiH(aq) -> Li+(aq) + AlH4-(aq)}$$

The strange thing is:

- Arrhenius definition cannot explain the reaction, since there is no $\ce{OH-}$ in the reaction formula.
- Also Brønsted–Lowry definition cannot explain the reaction, because the stuff which $\ce{LiH}$ gives to $\ce{AlH3}$ is not a proton (hydrogenium, $\ce{H+}$) but a protide (hydride, $\ce{H-}$).
- And as far as I know, this is the exact definition of Lewis acid and base written in my chemistry textbook:

> - Lewis acid: A substance which can receive unshared electron pair
> - Lewis base: A substance which can give unshared electron pair

leading to a conclusion that the above reaction also cannot be explained through the Lewis definition. Below are my questions:

- Is there anything wrong in my thought?
- Is that really an acid-base reaction? If it is, what kind of acid-base reaction is it?

Comment: "(aq)" *really*?

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, that is how it was written.

Comment: Then better get a new book, 'cause you'd sooner get a nuke in your basement then aqueous LiH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a Lewis acid-base reaction.

The hydride ion has a lone pair which is, in general, not bound to anything. The aluminium atom has at least one unpopulated orbital (typically taken to be a $\mathrm p_z$ orbital in a planar $\ce{AlX3}$ environment). This makes hydride a Lewis base and aluminium a Lewis acid. The association of hydride to aluminium is thus a Lewis acid-base reaction.

Comment: @PenPoint Hydride is the Lewis base. Lithium is technically also a Lewis acid, but it is not receiving here.